# \n doesn't work? What's wrong in my code?

Tags: java, android, newline, string-concatenation

I don't get the new line using the code below.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
String sum="";
int input = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum += i + input;
    display.setText(sum+"\n");
}
```

Comment: what is the `display` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should work:

```
String sum="";
int input = Integer.parseInt(value.getText().toString());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sum += i + input + "\n";
}
display.setText(sum);
```

Add the `\n` inside the loop.
Then display the whole string **after** the loop has completed.